# Method cannot return Average with Rails ActiveRecord + Raw SQL

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, activerecord

I'm learning how to code by building a Rails app (after completing the railstutorial.org) and I'm stuck on a weird issue.

The app is designed to list lunches (whereby employees can vote on whether or not they enjoyed the lunch.) A Lunch belongs to a Provider, and a Provider belongs to a Cuisine.

The app is also (attempting) to be multi-tenant, so there is a Member model, which is associated with the company.

The sum of all "positive likes" on a lunch divided by total lunch votes gives a lunch it's lunchscore.

All Lunch records, therefore have a provider_id, member_id, and lunchscore attribute.

My Problem: 
I am attempting to get the average lunchscore across many lunches, associated with a specific provider.  This is what is in my Provider.rb model:

```
def average_member_lunch_score(member_id)
    result = self.lunches.select("AVG(lunchscore) as average_lunchscore").where("date <= ? AND member_id = ? AND lunchscore > 0", Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day, member_id)
    return result.average_lunchscore
end
```

When I run this against a provider

```
arbys = Provider.find(id:2)
arbys.average_member_lunch_score(2)
```

I get the following result:

```
NoMethodError:   Lunch Load (0.1ms)  SELECT AVG(lunchscore) as average_lunchscore FROM "lunches" WHERE "lunches"."provider_id" = ? AND (date <= '2017-02-05 05:00:00.000000' AND member_id = 2 AND lunchscore > 0)  ORDER BY date ASC  [["provider_id", 1]]
undefined method `average_lunchscore' for #<ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation [#<Lunch id: nil>]>
```

However, if I try to manually tease apart the average_member_lunch_score method, and write in the SQL query itself, I seem to get most of the way there:

```
arbys.lunches.select("AVG(lunchscore) as average_lunchscore").where("date <= ? AND member_id = ? AND lunchscore > 0", Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day, 2)
  Lunch Load (0.1ms)  SELECT AVG(lunchscore) as average_lunchscore FROM "lunches" WHERE "lunches"."provider_id" = ? AND (date <= '2017-02-05 05:00:00.000000' AND member_id = 2 AND lunchscore > 0)  ORDER BY date ASC  [["provider_id", 1]]
+----+--------------------+
| id | average_lunchscore |
+----+--------------------+
|    | 0.8136429227338321 |
+----+--------------------+
1 row in set
```

It seems to me that it is perhaps something about the return method, or perhaps that it is returning a blank value for "id" that is causing the method to fail, whereas the query itself seems solid.

My end goal is to to be able to use this average value in a view, so I can type something like:

```
<%= @provider.average_member_lunch_score(current_user.member_id) %>
```

Can anyone help explain why the query works, but the method fails? Also, why is the query returning an "id" column, even though it's not in my select statement?

Answer (score 0):

I eventually answered this, with the help of others.  It seems there was a problem with breaking this out into raw SQL, so using the built in active record average method made this much easier (and work!)

```
def average_member_lunch_score(member_id)
    return self.lunches.where("date <= ? AND member_id = ? AND lunchscore > 0", Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day, member_id).average("lunchscore")
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, aggregation is done after the WHERE; to filter aggregated values, you have to use [HAVING](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#having) instead:

```ruby
lunches.select("AVG(lunchscore) as average_lunchscore").
    where("date <= ? AND member_id = ?", ...).
    having("AVG(lunchscore) > 0")
```